# Distributing python on Mac, Linux, and Windows using cx_freeze: can I generate all apps from one platform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm setting up a scripted build of a cross-platform python app (Python 3) and I'd like to create all the distributables from linux. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no

I've been doing something similiar recently (using cx_Freeze with Python 3). If you set up Python inside Wine, you can generate a Windows build, but I had to copy some DLLs in before it worked properly (cx_Freeze calls a Windows API function that's not implemented in Wine). I've not run into any way of packaging applications for Macs without actually having a Mac.

Perhaps someone should set up a community build service so people could build distributables for different platforms for each other. That doesn't get round the problem of testing, though.

Comment: sir, its been some time since this question was posted. Have any methods come up till then?

Comment: Not as far as I know. To use WINE to build Windows executables, I think [this function](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/imagehlp/modify.c#L44) would need to be written (it's currently marked as 'fixme' and 'stub').